# In 2020 do i need to call "removeEventListener" on 2nd initialization?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, removeeventlistener

I have continuous animation, made with [gsap library](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline). I'm using `mouseover`/`mouseout` events to pause/resume this animation. On window resize event I'm making re-initialization. My question is: do I need to call `removeEventListener` on 2nd initialization?

Here is the code/scenario:

```
const scroll = {

    create: function (el) {

        this.scrollAnimation = gsap.timeline({
            repeat: -1
        });

        // another piece of awesome code here...

        this.create__addMouseEvents(el);
    },
    create__addMouseEvents: function (el) {

        // here, on window resize event( when i call update(), during re-initialization ), do i need to call "removeEventListener"?

        el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => this.scrollAnimation.pause());

        el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => this.scrollAnimation.resume());

    },

    update: function () {
        // 
        // destroy old "scrollAnimation" if it's already exists
        if (this.scrollAnimation) {
            this.scrollAnimation.kill();
        }
        // 
        // reinit
        this.init();
    },

    init: function () {
        
        // some awesome code here...

        this.create(el);
    }
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    
    scroll.init();

});


let windowResizeTimer;
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    
    clearTimeout(windowResizeTimer);
    
    windowResizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        
        scroll.update();

    }, 150);

});
```

Comment: if you are going to call `addEventListener` again, then, yes, you'll want to remove the previous one, or else both will be called ... this hasn't changed in 2020, and is unlikely to change in 2021 either, since adding multiple event listeners to the one event is kind of a thing that can be useful

Comment: of course, since you add it like `el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => this.scrollAnimation.pause());` you'll never be able to remove it

Comment: oh, wait ... is `el` a new element each time you `this.create(el);` if so, and the old `el` no longer exists, then you wont need to remove the event listener on a non-existent element

Comment: @JaromandaX i thought maybe modern browsers can handle such things on their own. nope, `el` is alwasy the same

Comment: modern browsers don't have the ability to know if you really want to keep an old event listener or not - that would require a level of intelligence beyond the modern browser - as I said, having multiple listeners for the same event is quite common and can be useful - check my last comment though, perhaps you don't have the issue at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are currently adding a new event to the browser with every update. A simple solution would be the following:

```js
const scroll = {
  eventsAlreadyAdded: false,
  create: function (el) {
    this.scrollAnimation = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1 });
    // another piece of awesome code here...

    if (!scroll.eventsAlreadyAdded) {
      this.create__addMouseEvents(el);
      scroll.eventsAlreadyAdded = true;
    }
  },
  create__addMouseEvents: function (el) { /* .. */ },
  update: function () { /* .. */ },
  init: function () { /* .. */ }
}
```

Since you are not instantiating the scroll object, you have to change the global reference scroll.eventsAlreadyAdded.

Alternatively, you can slightly rewrite the code so that you are working on a instantiated variable (not tested):

```js
class Scroll {
  /**
   * Returns the element
   * @type {Node}
   */
  static get element() {
    return document.querySelector('THE ELEMET SELECTOR');
  }

  /**
   * Initial the scroll event to given element
   * @param {Node} el the element that will get an animation
   */
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el;

    /**
     * Remembers whether the events have already been attached to the element
     * @type {boolean}
     */
    this.eventsAlreadyAdded = false;

    /**
     * The timeline instanze from gsap
     * @type {Timeline}
     */
    this.scrollAnimation = null;

    this.create();
  }

  create() {
    this.scrollAnimation = gsap.timeline({
      repeat: -1
    });

    // another piece of awesome code here...
    this.addMouseEvents();
  }

  addMouseEvents() {
    if (this.eventsAlreadyAdded) return;
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => this.scrollAnimation.pause());
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => this.scrollAnimation.resume());
    this.eventsAlreadyAdded = true;
  }

  update() {
    if (this.scrollAnimation) {
      this.scrollAnimation.kill();
    }
    this.create();
  }
}

let scroll = null;
let windowResizeTimer = null;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  scroll = new Scroll(Scroll.element)
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if (!scroll) return;
  if (windowResizeTimer) clearTimeout(windowResizeTimer);
  windowResizeTimer = setTimeout(() => { scroll.update(); }, 150);
});
```